# Como iterar sobre uma string obtendo os índices de cada caractere em C++?

Tags: c++, foreach

Exemplo feito em Python:

```
editor = 'Luiz'

for contador, letra in enumerate(editor):
   print(f"A letra '{letra}' está no índice {contador} ")
```

Eu queria saber se é possível fazer esse tipo de contador dentro do `foreach` em C++, como no código acima em Python.

Eu percebi que no C++ existe uma função chamada `enum`, que é bem parecida com o `enumerate` do Python, mas eu não sei se faz a mesma coisa, só comparei porque achei os nomes das duas funções muito parecidos. Ele faz?

Mas enfim, tem ou não tem como colocar um contador **dentro do `foreach`** em C++?

Exemplo do `foreach` em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string editor = "Luiz";
   for (auto l : editor) cout << "Letra: " << l << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`enum` não é uma uma função. Veja a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) dele.

A forma mais simples de fazer isso é adicionar um contador externo para manter o controle, não é a solução mais bonita, mas funciona:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string editor = "Luiz";
   int i = 0;
   for (auto l : editor) cout << "Letra: " << l << " Índice: " << i++ << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2uIHoW). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/pkxojwtotv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/ForRangeIndex.cpp).

Ou pode usar o `for` normal que já conhece pelas perguntas anteriores, esse é um caso que ele pode ser mais útil, existem formas diferentes justamente para atender cada situação, não precisa usar sempre do mesmo jeito, esse caso eu usaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string editor = "Luiz";
   for (int i = 0; i < editor.length(); i++) cout << "Letra: " << editor[i] << " Índice: " << i << endl;
}
```

É possível usar outras formas também, até juntando a informação do elemento com o índice, como Python faz, mas é mais complexo e menos eficiente, Python faz assim porque não tem o `for` padrão (até tem um laço simples mas o pessoal acha que é sacrilégio usar). Faça o simples.

Answer (score 1):

O `enumerate` é necessário no Python já que a linguagem não tem o `for` “tradicional”, onde o programador cria uma variável contadora (geralmente `i`) e vai a incrementando em cada iteração. Por causa disso, se você precisar dos índices, é comum usar a função em questão.

Em C++, a opção que me parece mais trivial para fazer com o código que você já tem é manter um contador externo e ir o incrementando em cada iteração. Algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
   string editor = "Luiz";
 
   int i = 0;
   for (auto l : editor) cout << "Letra: " << l << " Índice: " << i++ << endl;
 
   return 0;
}
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/zDbGzY)</sup>

O operador na expressão `i++` chama-se *postfix increment operator*. Ele basicamente retorna o valor de seu operando e, em seguida, o incrementa. [Saiba mais.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec)

Você pode ver outras alternativas [nesta pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1315041/7445826). No entanto, todas as opções mostradas me parecem acabar complicando desnecessariamente.

---

Sobre o `enum` citado na pergunta, não se trata de uma função, mas sim um recurso da linguagem para que se faça a definição de [enumerações](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(tipo_de_dado)).